# Can moderators see or handle flags on their own answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

I've just saw a moderator give a 
"link only" answer to a post. According to what I know, those type of answers should be avoided.

And then I wondered. Is there any chance that this moderator will handle the flag if I will add one?

Comment: Did you wait a bit to see if the answer was updated/edited? Some times we all post answers and explain them in the next minute or two.

Comment: @Sergio - good point - YES. It's been some time (~30 min)

Comment: Link only answers come under "not good" but they don't automatically become flag worthy

Comment: That is why I disagree that people should quickly stick a tiny bit of an answer in with the intention of adding to it. Why bother? You might get downvotes for the weak answer, finish your edit and wait to hope to get more upvotes. The downvoters might not come back so needlessly lose rep, as do you, and the answer has invalid votes. I don't see the point or benefit of posting with the intention to edit. Especially if it's just a link or without the edit a half-baked answer.

Comment: I can see both of your arguments but this is far from being the discussion here :)

Comment: @RichardTingle You're right, they automatically become delete-worthy.  Note, there's no grace period.  The fastest gun in the west tactics are not immune from moderation.  If someone posts a link-only answer and fleshes it out later, that answer is perfectly subject to deletion before they flesh it out (because we have no clue if they'll actually flesh it out).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Moderarors are trusted with all flags.

Normally we defer handling to someone else at the first hint of a conflict of interest. Generally I don't even touch flags on answers that are competing with mine in the interest of impartiality.