# What happens when flagging a moderator?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

I was curious about the independence of justice and moderation with those that embody them on the forums: the moderators.

I wasn't asking on the way the community, its users, such as me, can control moderators.

This is only an example but for instance if a moderator becomes rude on a forum and is flagged, who will moderate? Would he take part to his moderation case? Does it implicate his moderator qualification?

Comment: Small old nitpick; calling SE sites forums gets some frowns. *Q/A sites* is a better choice.

Comment: @PhMgBr small nitpick: pointing out small copyediting mistakes instead of using the [edit] button to fix them.

Comment: @enderland well, I've observed that sometimes editing stuff like this instead of commenting doesn't teach the OP anything. *Why did he edit that?* In extreme cases it even gets to rollback wars. I'm pretty sure you know this yourself. And hell, I'm lazy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's good form for moderators to defer to someone else on the moderation team. This doesn't *have* to happen, but most moderators I know feel weird about handling flags on their own content, even if the outcome is very obvious.

If you're ever curious about why a flag had the outcome it did, you are always welcome to ask on your site's meta, where someone, either a user or a moderator, can help give feedback as to why a flag had the outcome it did. In other words, **the first check is the community on meta.** If the community disagrees with how a moderator handled a particular case, that will become clear on meta, and hopefully result in a change in moderation practices.

However, in your hypothetical: if a moderator becomes intractably volatile and rude, there are definite routes of escalation. **The second check is the Community Management team.** Community Managers are actual employees of Stack Exchange, responsible (among other things) for the health of each Stack Exchange community. They step in when some issue presents itself that moderators can't handle - including issues with the moderator team itself. Flags won't put you in touch with them, though - to get in contact with a community manager, use the [Contact Us link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) at the bottom of each page. Be sure to express your concerns in clear, succinct detail to get their attention and receive a well-considered outcome/response.

Answer (score 10):

> This is only an example but for instance if a moderator becomes rude on a forum and is flagged, who will moderate? Would he take part to his moderation case? Does it implicate his moderator qualification?

I want to add as a moderator that nearly all current moderator guidance is to defer to other site moderators (or the SE community team when appropriate) in situations like this.

The exception is meta, sometimes I will respond to posts on meta asking about moderation actions I took part in.

Comment: So, this means that if a post from "Moderator A" receives a rude flag, Moderator A is still able to see and process that flag? I was believing that a mod was automatically disallowed by the system to take actions on flags that target his own content but as you put it now it seem more of a social convention rule. Is this the case?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202222/can-moderators-see-or-handle-flags-on-their-own-answers.